# What is this motherboard socket?

Tags: motherboard, processor-socket

I'm getting a small motherboard alongside a CD.

I'm trying to figure out what the socket is.
According to Google, it originally came with a Core 2 Duo in a Pegatron C15B embedded PC.
It also may have been included in some toshiba laptops according to Google.

I'm unsure if it's HANNSTAR J-MV-4 or HANNSTAR J-MY-4. The image looks like a Y but Google suggests otherwise.

What is this CPU socket?

I'm just using this as a dummy PC to test old OS's on... That's if the board actually works still. The seller does not even know.

[image: Please Embed.]

Comment: Im not sure whats going on because the photo is NOT a land grid array (LGA anything) It obviously accepts pins of some sort but your answer of LGA775 is accepted.  Maybe the the photo does not match the board in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this CPU socket?

LGA 775

> Sockets Supported: LGA775

[Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E8400](https://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB)

It appears the HANNSTAR J-MV-4 was an AMD motherboard based on my research.

Comment: My answer is based on the fact, the author indicated the motherboard is an Intel motherboard, and came with Core 2 Duo processor.

Comment: there's no reason your comment shouldn't be part of your answer, since it explains the answer's basis.